# Mouse cursor skipping when moved

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, ubuntu-drivers

I am on a Razer blade 2018 advanced with Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver. For some reason, if I wait around 5 seconds before last moving the mouse cursor, then move the cursor ever so slightly, the cursor skips across the screen. How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: This can potentially be an issue that you should file a bug for. Please open the terminal and type `ubuntu-bug`, follow onscreen directions, and then when the browser opens fill out as much information as possible.